# TFS server was lost while backend SQL Server is intact. How can I migrate source code to VSTS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I found migration guide which uses command line. However, since there is no TFS server, I can't use the TFS migration tool.

A few workaround ideas I have ...

- Can I export data from SQL Server directly and then import that into VSTS?
- Can I install TFS (fresh new install on new VM) and connect to the existing SQL Server somehow?

I have no idea if above idea would work. If not, what possible options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reinstall the TFS application tier. When the wizard opens, you can choose "Application Tier Only" which will walk you through connecting it to the databases.

Make sure you reinstall the same version of TFS you were using before (including Update) -- if you were using TFS 2015 Update 3 before, reinstall TFS 2015 Update 3. Don't try to install Update 4 or Update 2.

Comment: When I click on 'List Available Databases', I get "The user does not have permission to perform this action" message. I actually don't know which user I'm using. What user should I use and where to change ?