# when using TFS application-tier only , where to change user?

Tags: tfs

I have a Data tier (SQLserver) but lost Application tier.So,I'm trying to install TFS app and connect (remotely) DB. People say I just need to install the same version of TFS app in new server and connect DB using 'Appl tier only' installation.

When I click on 'List Available  Databases' , I see "The user does not have permission to perform this action'. But, I don't know where to specify user here. It never asked when I click on 'App Tier only' wizard.  I guess it's running as my account and don't think that has enough permission to connect DB via TFS app. (Although I have access to SQL server)

Comment: related to my previous question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50224039/tfs-server-was-lost-while-backend-sql-server-is-intact-how-can-i-migrate-source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to logged into SQL Server with an available user account, then assigned `sysadmin` role to your current setup user. Then try it again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your current (setup) user can not connect to needed sql databases because tfs user account you will set on next page (Application Tier Settings). Maybe you just with local admin. You may install sql management studio on your new server and check this.